# how to filter data frame with conditions of columns?

Tags: rstudio

I have a table with a column "date-eval" and I would like to select only the dates after the "31/12/2015" under rstudio, how to do, knowing that I try with the subset function.

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use package `dplyr` to achieve this. Because you did not provide an example, I assume that you are doing with a data frame.

Here is an example:

`library(dplyr)`

`filter(Your_Data, date-eval >= "XXXX-XX-XX" & date-eval <= "XXXX-XX-XX")`